# Collision in Godot Engine, 2D game

Tags: godot

I want the inscription "hello" to be displayed in case of a collision with an object! How to do it? And what should be used?

I tried to do this using the Area2D node, but nothing worked :(
I tried to use the following code:

```
func print_msg():
    print("Hello")

func _on_area_entered(): (I attached it)
    print_msg()
```

> Before that, I made a player using KinematicBody2D and made him move. And made blocks for walking

Comment: Can you please add more details and the code you tested it with so far?

Answer (score 3):

Since you've left things very ambiguous I'll try to explain it to the best of what I understood

Here I have the basic setup with a `RigidBody2D` and `Area2D`:

[image]

And here's the main script:

```
extends Node2D

func message_area(thing):
    print("Hello! (Area Entered)")

func message_body(thing): # you were probably missing this
    print("Hello! (Body Entered)")

func _ready():
    $Area2D.connect("area_entered",self,"message_area")
    $Area2D.connect("body_entered",self,"message_body")
```

Now when you press play the rigid body will fall into Area2D and when it does it will output this:

> Hello! (Body Entered)

My best guess is you only connected the `area_entered` signal but not the `body_entered` which is why nothing was being printed when the object entered  the Area2D

You can further follow on [how to connect signals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NK_SYVO7lMA) & [How Area2D works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQyyD-ykAHU)

And I'd recommend you post code or explain what you've tried (preferably with images) so people can understand your problem better and help better :)

---

**Edit:**

If you want to change the visibility of the thing entered/collided you  have 2 options:

```
...

func message_body(thing):
    print("Hello! (Body Entered)")

    thing.visible=true #option 1
    thing.modulate.a=0.0 #option 2 (you can also use self_modulate)
```

Option 1 is the equivalent of pressing the eye icon [image]

Option 2 changes the alpha value i.e. decides how much transparent your object should be and lies between 0 & 1 where 0=completely invisible, 1=completely visible, 0.5=50% visible and so on...

Equivalent of changing :
[image]

---

*However*, since you said "with a certain object" you can add a condition before toggling the visibility:

```
func message_body(thing):
    print("Hello! (Body Entered)")
    
    if(thing is KinematicBody2D): # or you can create a custom class and use it's `class_name`
        thing.visible=true
        thing.modulate.a=0.0
    
    # or

    if(thing.name =="Main Player"):
        thing.visible=true
        thing.modulate.a=0.0
    
    # etc etc
```

I recommend you read [this](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html) if you already haven't

Comment: Good demonstration. It shows how `area_entered` doesn't check if "this area" was entered, it checks if a different area node entered this one.

Comment: Sorry for the very non-detailed question!                                                               
             Thank you very much! I have one more question: 
How do I make it so that when colliding with a certain object, instead of displaying an inscription, another object becomes visible (visibility was disabled before that)??

Comment: @Kirill does the edit solve your query?